# Using GitHub's graphql API for finding number of addtions, deletions and changes done by a user during a commit on each file

Tags: python, git, github, graphql

Well I have been trying to convert the REST API service provided by GitHub that I am using in my code to graphql and in the process I am stuck on the phase of converting number of changes done by a user during a commit. I am trying to extract the number of insertions, deletions and changes done by a user on each file (instead of total) using graphql API and python. Can someone help me in finding things out in this? I have tried reading the schema file and have reached to this query only.

```
query GetRepositoryLanguages($owner: String!, $repoName: String!) {
  repository(owner: $owner, name: $repoName) {
    defaultBranchRef {
      target {
        on
        Commit {
          tree {
            entries {
              name
              lineCount
              extension
              language {
                name
              }
              object {
                on
                Blob {
                  byteSize
                }
              }
            }
          }
          history {
            edges {
              node {
                additions
                deletions
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't paste code in a quote block, it's unreadable. Please edit to use a code block instead.